# define-modify-macro with operator argument

Tags: macros, common-lisp, setf

In [Section 12.4 of On Lisp](https://web.archive.org/web/20140708014517id_/http://dunsmor.com/lisp/onlisp/onlisp_16.html#SEC94), Paul Graham writes, *"Unfortunately, we can't define a correct `_f` with `define-modify-macro`, because the operator to be applied to the generalized variable is given as an argument."*

But what's wrong with something like this?

```
(define-modify-macro _f (op operand)
  (lambda (x op operand)
    (funcall op x operand)))

(let ((lst '(1 2 3)))
  (_f (second lst) #'* 6)
  lst)

=> (1 12 3)
```

Has there perhaps been a change made to define-modify-macro in ANSI Common Lisp that wasn't valid at the time On Lisp was written? Or are there reasons other than the one stated for not using `define-modify-macro` here?

It appears that Graham want's to be able to make a call such as

```
(_f * (second lst) 6)
```

rather than

```
(_f #'* (second lst) 6)
```

But surely that's not in keeping with a Lisp2 such as Common Lisp?

Answer (score 2):

According to both [Lispworks's Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_2.htm) and [CLtL2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node80.html) (look for `define-modify-macro`), the function is assumed to be a *symbol* (to a function or a macro). As far as I know, the following definition might not be conforming the specification:

```lisp
(define-modify-macro _f (op operand)
  (lambda (x op operand)
    (funcall op x operand)))
```

But of course, it is possible that an implementation allows it.
To be sure you are conforming to the standard, you can define your own function, or even a macro:

```lisp
(defmacro funcall-1 (val fun &rest args)
  `(funcall ,fun ,val ,@args))

(define-modify-macro _ff (&rest args)  funcall-1)

(let ((x (list 1 2 3 4)))
  (_ff (third x) #'+ 10)
  x)
```

If you wanted to have the function as a second argument, you could define another macro:

```
(defmacro ff (fun-form place &rest args)
  `(_ff ,place ,fun-form ,@args))
```

Basically, your approach consists in wrapping `funcall` in  `define-modify-macro`, and give the desired function as an argument of that function. At first sight, it looks like a hack, but as we can see below, this gives the same macroexanded code as the one in *On Lisp*, assuming we modify the latter a little.

The macroexpansion of the above is:

```lisp
(LET ((X (LIST 1 2 3 4)))
  (LET* ((#:G1164 X) (#:G1165 (FUNCALL #'+ (THIRD #:G1164) 10)))
    (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA (CDDR #:G1164) #:G1165))
  X)
```

The version in *On Lisp* behaves as follows:

```lisp
(defmacro _f (op place &rest args)
   (multiple-value-bind (vars forms var set access)
       (get-setf-expansion
        place)
        `(let* (,@(mapcar #'list vars forms)
               (, (car var) (,op ,access ,@args)))
           ,set)))


(let ((x (list 1 2 3 4)))
  (_f * (third x) 10)
  x)
```

Macroexpansion:

```
(LET ((X (LIST 1 2 3 4)))
  (LET* ((#:G1174 X) (#:G1175 (* (THIRD #:G1174) 10)))
    (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA (CDDR #:G1174) #:G1175))
  X)
```

Here, the `*` is injected directly by the macroexpansion, which means that the resulting code has no possible runtime overhead (though compilers would probably handle your `(funcall #'+ ...)` equally well). If you pass `#'+` to the macro, it fails to macroexpand. This is the major difference with your approach, but not a big limitation. In order to allow the *On Lisp* version to accept `#'*`, or even `(create-closure)` as an operator, it should be modified as follows:

```lisp
 (defmacro _f (op place &rest args)
    (multiple-value-bind (vars forms var set access)
        (get-setf-expansion
         place)
         `(let* (,@(mapcar #'list vars forms)
                (, (car var) (funcall ,op ,access ,@args)))
            ,set)))
```

(see the call to `funcall`)

The previous example is then expanded as follows, for `#'*`:

```lisp
(LET ((X (LIST 1 2 3 4)))
  (LET* ((#:G1180 X) (#:G1181 (FUNCALL #'* (THIRD #:G1180) 10)))
    (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA (CDDR #:G1180) #:G1181))
  X)
```

Now, it is exactly as your version. *On Lisp* uses `_f` to demonstrate how to use `get-setf-expansion`, and `_f` is a good example for that. But on the other hand, your implementation seems equally good.

Answer (score 1):

On the question of whether one might prefer to pass `*` or `#'*`, we can also note that the `define-modify-macro` version of `_f` and @coredump's adapted version (with `funcall`) both accept lambda forms in the op position with or without `#'` e.g. both `(lambda (x y) (* x y))` and `#'(lambda (x y) (* x y))`, whereas Graham's original version accepts only the former.

Interestingly in his book [Let over Lambda](http://www.letoverlambda.com/), Doug Hoyte draws attention to a remark by Graham in his book [ANSI Common Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html) that being able to omit the `#'` before a lambda form provides *"a specious form of elegance at best"* before going on to prefer to omit it.

I'm not taking a stand either way, merely pointing out that given Graham's choice for `_f`, the absence of the `#'` is no longer specious but necessary.